# Entity Framework Code First Filtering Results for retrieval

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Soft Delete Entity Framework Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698793/soft-delete-entity-framework-code-first)

Is there any way to filter the results for an entity before results are returned?
So say First or Find or whatever method I choose to use against the entity would not return anything older than 3 months let's say.  Also if I include the entity it would be filtered as such too.  I am trying to use this to implement a soft delete amongst other things

I would like this to be done internally somehow if possible so I can say `_db.SmallGroups.ToList()` and it would know what records to NOT bring back (ie older records, IsDeleted==true records) I don't want to have to put this logic in at every query point if possible

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This would be something to do in repositories.

Comment: But why do you ask [again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698793/soft-delete-entity-framework-code-first)?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can just specify your conditions in a *where* clause

```
DateTime threeMonthsAgo = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3);

var results = 
    (from t in context.MyTable where t.TheTime > threeMonthsAgo select t).First();
```

**UPDATE**

Based on your comment...

You can indeed build an expression that you can reuse as a *where* condition.

Here's an extension method I wrote that does that for *Contains* type of conditions (original source cited in the XML comments)

```
/// <summary>
/// Extension method that enables .Contains(obj) like functionality for Linq to Entities.
/// 
/// Source: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t645784-linq-where-clause.html
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TElement">The element being evaluated by the Where clause</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TValue">The value to match</typeparam>
/// <param name="valueSelector">Lamda for selecting matching values</param>
/// <param name="values">IEnumerable of the values</param>
/// <returns>Expression consumable by Linq to Entities that reflects semantics of .Contains(value)</returns>
/// <remarks>
/// Usage:
/// 
/// Replace expression like 
/// 
/// where ChildrenIDs.Contains(items.CategoryID)
/// 
/// with
/// 
/// .Where((BuildContainsExpression<Item, int>(item => item.CategoryID, ChildrenIDs))
/// 
/// NOTE: If the item collection is large, the SQL query will be as well.
/// </remarks>
static public Expression<Func<TElement, bool>> BuildContainsExpression<TElement, TValue>(Expression<Func<TElement, TValue>> valueSelector, IEnumerable<TValue> values)
{
    if (null == valueSelector)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("valueSelector");
    }
    if (null == values) { throw new ArgumentNullException("values"); }

    ParameterExpression p = valueSelector.Parameters.Single();
    if (!values.Any())
    {
        return e => false;
    }

    var equals = values.Select(value => (Expression)Expression.Equal(valueSelector.Body, Expression.Constant(value, typeof(TValue))));
    var body = equals.Aggregate<Expression>((accumulate, equal) => Expression.Or(accumulate, equal));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TElement, bool>>(body, p);
}
```

**Usage**

```
HashSet<long> productCodes = new HashSet<long>(); // Populate with some product codes to match

productCodeWhere = LinqToEntitiesUtil.BuildContainsExpression<Verbatim, long>(v => v.ProductCode, productCodes);

var matching = (from v in ctx.MyTable where MY_CONDITIONS select v)
    .Where(productCodeWhere);
```

Comment: My apologies.
I meant something more internal so if I were to say `_db.SmallGroups.ToList()` it would just know to ignore say ones over 3 months ago or ones with IsDeleted that way I don't have to enforce these rules at every query point but rather in one place.  Thank you.

Comment: Added an example of how one can reuse a *where* expression.