# Filtering navigation property in eager loading

Tags: entity-framework-5

I have been working with soft delete and now i want to load the navigation properties of my entity that are not "deleted". I have found a way, my problem this way is not to clear for me, there is another way to do this.

`Context.CreateSet().Include("Salary").Select(u => new {User= u, Salary = u.Salarys.Where(s => !s.Deleted)}).AsQueryable().Select(a => a.User).AsQueryable();`

Comment: There is a working soft delete solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698793/soft-delete-entity-framework-code-first/18985828#18985828

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eager loading doesn't support filtering. Your code can be simplified to:

```
var users = Context.CreateSet<User>()
                   .Select(u => new {
                       User = u,
                       Salary = u.Salaries.Where(s => !s.Deleted)
                    })
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(a => a.User);
```

`Include` is not needed because you are replacing it with your own query and `AsQueryable` is not needed because the query is `IQueryable` all the time till called `AsEnumerable` which will sqitch to Linq-to-Objects when selecting users and selected salaries. EF will take care of correctly fixing navigation properties for you.

Comment: This is the current solution, thanks, but EF doesn't support something more clear, this look like a trick.

Comment: Yes it is a trick because filtering navigation properties [is not supported](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1015345-allow-filtering-for-include-extension-method).

Comment: This solution need to be modified if salaries is a many to many relation? I test it in and dont work in a new use case where user tried to filter a navigation property having a many to many relation