# making a global filter for entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

For my models I have a `active` attribute on all of them, and i want to filter all inactive if the model was not displayed on the administration
What is the best way to do that, What I'm currently using is the following

in my base model class i have this method that filters the collections

```
public virtual IQueryable<T> GlobalDefaultScope<T>(IQueryable<T> c) where T : CModel<T>
{
    if (settings.is_admin)
    {
        c = c.Where(m => m.active);
    }
    return c;
}
```

and on my model for every relation i did the following method

```
DbSet<T> set ...
var X = set.Where(some filter);
var list = globalDefaultScope(X).ToList();
return list;
```

And now I'm having some serious problems when i want to eagerly load some subrelations using `include("Xmodel.Ymodel")` i called the `globalDefaultScope` in the `get` method for that collection that filters the collection but it keeps throwing this exception when some items in the collection are inactive

> **System.InvalidOperationException:** 
>     The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more 
>     of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable.

how can i fix this or how can i make this filter in a more elegant way because i'm really not very satisfied of how i implemented it.

please ask for Any missing information or code blocks or any details

**Update:**

I also found this [link](http://www.matthidinger.com/archive/2012/01/25/a-smarter-infrastructure-automatically-filtering-an-ef-4-1-dbset.aspx), but this way didn't work with eagerly loaded entries (`include()`)

**Update2:**

this is an example of how i use the include and where the error occurs

*In My Model*

```
public IQueryable<Dish> getSomeRelation(bool eagerly_load_sub_relation1, bool eagerly_load_sub_relation2)
        {
            var query = getQuery(...);
            //getQuery =>  query = db.Entry(obj).Collection(collection).Query() 
            //GlobalDefaultScope(query)
            if ( eagerly_load_sub_relation1){
                query = query.Include(m => m.sub_relation1);
            }
            if (eagerly_load_sub_relation2){
                query = query.Include("sub_relation2.sub_relation_of_sub_relation2");
            }
            return query;
        }
```

while i couldn't filter the relations in the include i did the following :

```
private ICollection<SubRelation1> _sub_relation1 {get; set;}
public ICollection<SubRelation1> sub_relation1 {
get 
{
   //something like:
   return GlobalDefaultScope(_sub_relation1 ).ToList(); 
}  
set;}
```

while we filter the results in sub_relation1, when i do db.SaveChanges() the mentioned error is thrown.

Comment: If you do the include() without applying the filter does it work, i.e. does the error go away. Can you show some code of how the include is applied.

Comment: @TommyGrovnes the Question is updated, Thanks.

Comment: @Hilmi can you please include the database tables as well.(**What I feel is that for your first relation ship you are not getting values as there might not be any data for that and you are trying to get second relation ship of null**)

Comment: Try a SecurityContext specified in Entity REST SDK http://entityrestsdk.codeplex.com

Answer (score 9):

You can create extension methods like

```
public static IQueryable<T> Where<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    source = source.Where("isActive == true"); // From System.linq.Dynamic Library
    source = Queryable.Where<T>(source, predicate);
    return source;
}
```

and use them like

```
var user = db.UserProfiles.Include("webpages_Roles").Where(u => u.UserId < 30);
```

This should work, Please Let me know if you need more information.

**Note : Please Add Nuget package for System.Linq.Dynamic to have dynamic Linq Library**

**Update 1:**

I have included IsActive in webpages_Roles and UsreProfile table of simple membership and also included one more table Role Priority which refers to webpages_Roles, for easy to use I have changed the all the relation ships to one to many(from many to many). now if I use code similar to yours, extension method gives error when there is any user for which there are no roles.

If I give roles to every user and I have priority for every roles then this won't give error.

Please Let me know if you still need any other info.

**Update 2**

You can create one extension Method like

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereActive<T>(this IQueryable<T> source)
        {
            return source.Where("isActive == true"); // From System.linq.Dynamic Library
        }
```

and call other methods like

```
var user = db.UserProfiles.Include("webpages_Roles").WhereActive().Where(u => u.UserId < 30);
```

or

```
var user = db.UserProfiles.Include("webpages_Roles").WhereActive().FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId < 30);
```

Please Let me know if you still need any other info.

Comment: Sir, It will be buggy to use this way, because you overridden the `Where` function, and in my code i use `Where First FirstOrDefault ...`  and many others, i'll have to loop over them and override them all, If i miss understood any thing please tell me, Thanks alot sir

Comment: Thanks alot sir, your way is nice, but i have to go all over the site and call `WhereActive` method on them, i'll just wait to find more centralized self controlled way to do this, if i didn't find anything (and it seems i won't) i'll choose and mark your answer as the chosen one. thanks again

Comment: I think this, creating (and promoting) a library which also makes you lose strong-typedness on the property instead of just creating an `IActivatedEntity` interface with a `bool IsActive` property and putting a type constraint of `where T : IActivatedEntity` on the `WhereActive()` extension method and applying that interface to your entities, goes a bit far imho.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

1. In OnModelCreating add an IsDeleted discriminator to every entity that can be soft deleted
2. Override SaveChanges and find all the entries to be deleted
3. Run SQL on these entries to set the IsDeleted discriminator then set their state to "detached"
4. Change any unique indexes to ignore any soft deleted records

You can find working code at this answer:
[How to soft delete using Entity Framework Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18985828/150342)

Comment: I think thats what i was looking for exactly !
but for now its not working with pre-generated views, i'll look for solution, THANKS alot sir

Comment: How can you do the same using database first or why isn't it possible?