# Creating object level permissions in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model

I am trying to get object-level permissions in MVC. I have looked all over for this but can only find examples that are 3+ years old and I can't seem to get it working.

Say I have 2 models:

```
public class Supplier
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> LinkedUsers { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Supplier> LinkedSuppliers { get; set; }
}
```

I also have this for my permissions.

```
public enum SupplierUserPermissions
{
    Edit = 1,
    View = 2,
}
```

Each `ApplicationUser` can be linked to many `Suppliers` and each `Supplier` can be linked to many `ApplicationUsers`

Entity Framework has created a table with FK's on the user ID and the supplier ID.

How can I create object level permissions for each user? For example, a user should be able to only **View** certain suppliers, but perhaps they can **Edit** another.

How should I build my models or how best can I implement this? I'm pretty sure standard role based security won't cut it for this, at least not cleanly, or am I mistaken?

Edit: I'm using ASP Identity 2 for my authentication.

Comment: What authentication system are you using? Forms, Windows? Is your user object linked with that system, eg. is your userId contained in an authentication cookie?

Comment: @PaulTaylor I'm using ASP Identity 2. Yes, my user object is linked with it but I can extend it as required. I've added that to the question now

Answer (score 0):

Global filtering could be used to achieve this.
have a look at this question and answer --> [making a global filter for entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18707139/making-a-global-filter-for-entity-framework)

This should give you a good starting point on how to implement global filtering for entity framework