# Add a condition to a list getter property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I have 2 poco objects:

```
public abstract class BasePoco
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}

public class FirstPoco : BasePoco
{
    public virtual List<SecondPoco> SecondPocos { get; set; }
}
public class SecondPoco : BasePoco
{
}
```

When I query a firstPoco object from my Repository implementation where Id == 10:

```
var first = Repository.Get<FirstPoco>(10);
```

I have a custom logic implemented in my Repository that all objects match:

```
x=>!x.IsDeleted
```

But is there some way how to implement this for related collection of SecondPoco?

At the moment I would have to write:

```
var secondCollection = first.SecondPocoes.Where(x=>!x.IsDeleted);
```

Is there a way how to do this generically?

**EDIT**
this is my Get method:

```
private IQueryable<T> GetQueryable<T>() where T : BasePoco
{
    return _context.Set<T>().AsQueryable().Where(x => !x.IsDeleted);
}
public T Get<T>(int id) where T : BasePoco
{
    return GetQueryable<T>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
}
```

Comment: I think you need to show the implementation for your `Get` method. That's most likely where you're going to want to add common (likely abstract) logic to always enforce the `! IsDeleted` clause.

Comment: @Yuck see the question updated. I don't think you understand what I am trying to achieve here. I am not calling .Get<SecondPoco>() on each element of the SecondPocoes list. The Get method is never called for SecondPoco in this case

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18707139/making-a-global-filter-for-entity-framework

Comment: @VojtechB are all of the poco's the same? Is it possible instead of having a List<SecondPoco> Could you have a List<IMyPoco>?

Comment: There's an interesting solution in [this clip](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2014/DEV-B417#fbid=).

Comment: @Robert My poco's are not the same but they all derive from BasePoco

Comment: @GertArnold your solution was the one I selected!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what would make sense to me. Just wrap a public property around your actual collection.

```
public class FirstPoco : BasePoco
{
    private virtual List<SecondPoco> _secondPocos;
    public virtual List<SecondPoco> SecondPocos 
    {
       get {return _secondPocos.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted);} 
       set { _secondPocos = value;} 
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this the most generic solution I can get? If I have dozens of POCOs this doesn't seem to be much of help.

Answer (score 0):

If they all derive from the same base object and the IsDeleted Method is in each of them:

```
public abstract class BasePoco
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}

public class FirstPoco : BasePoco
{
    public virtual List<BasePoco> ChildPocos { get; set; }
}

public class SecondPoco : BasePoco
{

}

var secondCollection = first.ChildPoco.Where(x=>!x.IsDeleted);
```

I don't know what you want to do with them but you could get all of them with a simple call.

```
public IEnumerable<BasePoco> Build()
    {
        var basePoco = typeof (BasePoco);
        return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
            .Where(type => entityRule.IsAssignableFrom(type) && type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null)
            .Select(Activator.CreateInstance)
            .Cast<BasePoco>();
    }
```

That would give you a list of all the classes that inherit from base poco and you could iterate them to get what you want.