# Pattern for Multi User ASP.NET with SQL/LINQ

Tags: sql, asp.net, linq, design-patterns

I have a SQL+ASP.NET situation for which I suspect there might exists a design pattern.

I have a site where users can register and then enter their own data. The users can only see their own data and never anything else.

My question is: Is there a way to somehow simplify this process. All SQL commands clearly need to be filtered based on the user ID, and ASP Web Forms doesn't really allow this in a simple way. Is there a way to maybe produce LINQ objects or something similar that can automatically extend every SQL command sent to the SQL Server with a User ID parameter?

Comment: This is known as a *multi-tenant architecture*. I'd recommend you do some reading on the subject, starting [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2213006/861716) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement sounds like you just need **global filters**. The suport varies from ORM to ORM but see for example how nHibernate implements it:

http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/filters.html

Filters are part of your model description and can be applied at entity level and at navigation property level.

```
<class name="MyClass" ...>
   ...
   <filter name="myFilter" condition=":myFilterParam = MY_FILTERED_COLUMN"/>
</class>
```

You selectively enable filters in current session.

```
session.EnableFilter("myFilter").SetParameter("myFilterParam", "some-value");
```

Entity framework doesn't exactly follows the same approach, rather, you just overload your LINQ operators so that the tedious work is encapsulated once:

[making a global filter for entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18707139/making-a-global-filter-for-entity-framework)

or you use one of existing custom extensions that suport global filters

https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/wiki/EF-Query-Filter-%7C-Entity-Framework-Dynamic-Instance-and-Global-Filters