# EF5: How to alter the default Delete function to implement my own

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Well, here is my situation:

We have tables that we dont want ever to delete the data. There is a column which is called isDeleted that is supposed to be updated instead instead of deleting it.

I want to develop the accompanying web app with EF5 but i have a problem there. How do i implement that restriction?

I could use stored procedures to delete and select but i was hoping for a way to use the standard functions in EF, just changing how they work. Which way is less arduous and what options i have to achieve what i want, since i´m guessing i´m not the first person to ask for this?

Comment: I shudder to suggest this, but have you considered a trigger? You could do an `instead of delete`.

Comment: Yeah, but the next select will still get the data..what i want is all select calls to ignore those "deleted" lines

Comment: @Sergio you are talking about two different things now, soft deleting the data and filtering out record that have been `deleted`.

Comment: I'm adding on to the suggestions that I don't like, but you could wrap a view around the table which only returns "non-deleted" records, and make that your entity. You would need triggers on the view at that point.

Comment: @SOfanatic Well..arent those related? i want to soft delete yes, but i dont want that soft deleted data to be visible ordinarily on the app right? i want to soft delete it for security and traceability but i dont want to always have to exclude records having IsDeleted=true before using the data... i would think this is the regular use of soft deleting?

Comment: I guess a better question would be, how could i overload the linq select to apply whatever filter i want before returning the data?

Comment: @Sergio for soft delete look into this: http://blog.jorgef.net/2010/12/ef-soft-delete.html and for filtering out soft deleted records look into this: http://www.agile-code.com/blog/entity-framework-code-first-applying-global-filters/

Comment: I personally hate this form of "Soft Delete". The blog post by Jorge Fioranelli only solves one of a whole host of problems. You can try using a View with `Instead of Delete` Trigger. The upside is that you don't have to shotgun your code with `.Where(x => x.Deleted == false)`

Comment: I posted a fairly complete solution over here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18985828/150342

Comment: @Colin, please make your comment into an answer so i can accept it

Comment: Answer added as requested

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override SaveChanges method of your DbContext. E.g. you want to forbid deleting products. You can save entities with IsDeleted flag set to true instead of deleting them:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var deletedPersonEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries<Person>()
                                    .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Deleted);

    foreach (var e in deletedPersonEntries)
    {
        e.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
        e.Entity.IsDeleted = true;
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Another option - raise exception if someone tries to delete product:

```
if (deltedProductEntries.Any())
    throw new Exception("You should not delete products!");
```

You also can simply set entities state to unchanged, but I don't think its very good solution.

Comment: For your third option, I'd go with `e.State = EntityState.Unchanged; e.Entity.IsDeleted = true;` so that only `IsDeleted` is updated, not everything else as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

1. In OnModelCreating add an IsDeleted discriminator to every entity that can be soft deleted
2. Override SaveChanges and find all the entries to be deleted
3. Run SQL on these entries to set the IsDeleted discriminator then set their state to "detached"
4. Change any unique indexes to ignore any soft deleted records

You can find working code at this answer:
[How to soft delete using Entity Framework Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18985828/150342)

You could also use stored procedures instead of the code used in steps 2 and 3 - and I've been looking at how [EF6 generates the stored procedures for you](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Code%20First%20Insert/Update/Delete%20Stored%20Procedure%20Mapping). You add code that looks like this:

`modelBuilder.Entity<AdministrativeArea>().MapToStoredProcedures();`

and that results in a migration that includes this:

```
        CreateStoredProcedure(
            "dbo.AdministrativeArea_Delete",
            p => new
                {
                    ID = p.Int(),
                },
            body:
                @"DELETE [dbo].[AdministrativeAreas]
                  WHERE ([ID] = @ID)"
        );
```

Now it's a case of altering the sql in the migration from a delete to an update. It wouldn't be too arduous to do it with text/replace but wouldn't it be cool if we could change the template used to generate the `CreateStoredProcedure` calls?....

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW Foo
AS 
SELECT
    f.Id,
    f.Bar,
    f.Baz,
    f.Qux
FROM Foo_Table
Where f.Deleted = 0;

CREATE TRIGGER Foo_Delete
ON Foo
Instead of Delete
AS 
BEGIN
    Update
        Foo_Table f
    SET
        f.Deleted = 1
    WHERE
        f.Id IN (SELECT Id from Deleted)
END;
```