# Can I enforce Entityramework to execute UPDATE even though that record is DELETED afterwards?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, entity-framework, entity

I want to execute a Db UPDATE whenever a particular object is Removed from the context in Entity Framework.

But as it is deleted in the end, EF does not execute an UPDATE in the Db.

Can I enforce EF to really execute a Db UPDATE and then DELETE the entity afterwards?

Thanks

PS : The reason I want to enforce an UPDATE before DELETE is because there is a trigger on the Db which helps me obtain some info for later use.

Comment: How to alter the default Delete function to implement my own: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18985295/150342

Comment: Colin, I can override the behaviour and maybe get the specific entries marked as delete; and I can mark them as Modified, call SaveChanges(). And re-mark them as DELETE. And SaveChanges() again -but I am not sure if it can have negative side effects to call Savechanges two times..

Comment: Why not create a `DELETE` trigger instead, as that's what you're really doing?

Comment: Bcoz, the data I need won't be achievable until I write it to Db -via Update.

Comment: I don't see there being a problem with calling SaveChanges twice - it's a standard way of coping with database exceptions for example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj592904. The other way to do it is in a stored procedure: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19248216/150342

Answer (score 1):

Triggers and EF are not a good combination as the triggers are largely opaque in your code and making someone do an update before a delete to ensure a particular trigger fires would be confusing.

Less hacky solutions:

If you have to use a trigger (i.e. the DB is used by other apps that rely on the trigger) modify your trigger or create a new trigger that fires on delete and saves the required information.

Encapsulate your trigger code in a method and ensure that method is used for all updates and deletes by your app.