# Can I add a discriminator via a custom code first convention?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I add a discriminator column to all my entities in order to facilitate [soft delete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18985828/150342).

Currently I do it by specifying it on each entity one by one:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().Map(m => m.Requires("IsDeleted").HasValue(false));
   modelBuilder.Entity<Bar>().Map(m => m.Requires("IsDeleted").HasValue(false));
   //etc etc
}
```

What I'd like to be able to do is specify it as a [Custom Code First Convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819164.aspx). My entities all inherit from a `ModelBase` class. So I can create a custom convention to map to stored procedures like this:

`modelBuilder.Types<ModelBase>().Configure(m => m.MapToStoredProcedures());`

but this is not available:

`modelBuilder.Types<ModelBase>().Configure(m => m.Requires("IsDeleted").HasValue(false));`

So, is there any way to add a discriminator to all entities that inherit from `ModelBase` other than doing it one by one?