# Override LINQ .Include(), possible?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I've been browsing the internet for this issue for quite some time, and I'm getting far fewer results pertaining to overriding LINQ methods. I'm not sure if it can be done, but I'm wondering if someone can either confirm whether this works or not, or suggest an alternative.

The situation is as follows (simplified for this question, of course)

We are using EF6 Code First to build our database. We have added a custom (abstract) base class from which ALL entities derive. This base class implements some fields we use for auditing (creation date, created by, modified date, ...), but we also implement a soft delete system by adding the **IsDeleted** (bool) property in the base class.

As far as our application is aware, items with `IsDeleted` == true must never be returned.

The DataModel is as follows (again, simplified)

```
Company
    ---> 1 Company has many Departments
    Department
        ---> 1 Department has many Adresses
        Address
```

In the past, I've tried to create a general method for retrieval that eliminates the IsDeleted objects, by creating an "override" to the tables in the DataContext (also a custom class because it automatically handles the audit fields).

For every table you find in a DataContext:

```
public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
```

We have added a second table that only returns non-deleted items.

```
public IQueryable<Company> _Companies 
{
    get { return this.Companies .Where(co => !co.IsDeleted); }
}
```

So we call `MyDataContext._Companies` instead of `MyDataContext.Companies`.
This works as intended. It nicely filter away the deleted items.

However, we noticed that the same is not true for the subsequent `.Include()` statement. If I call:

```
var companies = MyDataContext._Companies.Include(x => x.Departments);

//...
```

The deleted Departments from a Company are returned as well.

In our current situation, most of the core business logic has already been implemented, and these include statements are all over the place. They mostly relate to security. I can change all statements, but I'd rather first look for a way to do this without impacting the existing code too much.
This is the first application where the size of the queries does not allow us to call every set of entities separately (by using only the direct tables as opposed to include statements).

So my question is twofold:

- Can I override the `.Include(Func<x,y>)` method to automatically include a check on the `IsDeleted` flag for the selected entity?
- If overriding if possible, how do I combine the passed lambda expression with the additional check I want to execute?

So by calling

```
someTable.Include(x => x.MyRelatedEntity);
```

It would actually execute:

```
/* Not sure if this is proper syntax. I hope it explains what I'm trying to accomplish. */
someTable.Include(x => x.MyRelatedEntity.Where(y => !y.IsDeleted));
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction? Much appreciated!

*Note: I know there's not much code in my question. But I'm not even sure on what level I can implement this. If Include can't be overridden, is there another way?*

**Update**

I implemented the suggested solution, but am runnign into an issue with all database calls. The error is as follows:

```
Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 245:Condition member 'Company.IsDeleted' with a condition other than 'IsNull=False' is mapped. Either remove the condition on Company.IsDeleted or remove it from the mapping.
```

Reading up on this issue, it seems that if I use `IsDeleted` as a condition (i.e. the suggested solution), I cannot still use it as a property.

The problem then becomes: how do I delete something? Once it is deleted, it should never be returned. But a non-deleted item should be able to be deleted.

Is there any way in which I can filter the returned items by IsDeleted, **but am still allowed to set it to true and save it**?

Comment: What about changing the Company class?

You can try adding a property that selects non-deleted departments, or you can rename to make it work

Inside Company:
public IQueryable<Department> _Departments
{
    get { return this.Departments.Where(co => !co.IsDeleted); }
}

Then, use `someTable.Include(X=>X._Departments)`

Comment: How would you change it? Also, this is a simplified example, in reality there's 13 tables and 18-ish relations between them. Changing entities is possible, but only if it's in a way that doesn't impact the entire codebase.

Comment: Have a look at the model, you should be able to filter (I believe its called `Ignore`) rows when mapping to model. My recommendation is to not touch the `Include` method at all, it is at the wrong level.

Comment: It seems Ignore actually drops a field (most Google results for this end up being about the NotMapped property). I'm trying to force the property to be evaluated, not ignored. If I misunderstood your comment, sorry :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution you're looking for is to require entities have an `IsDeleted` value of `false`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
    .Map( emc => emc.Requires( "IsDeleted" ).HasValue( false ) );
```

Now only companies with `IsDeleted == false` will be retrieved from the DB

Update from comment:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
    .Map( emc => 
    {
        emc.MapInheritedProperties();
        emc.Requires( "IsDeleted" ).HasValue( false );
    } )
    .Ignore( c => c.IsDeleted );
```

Update: test code which was successful (helper methods found [here](http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2013/10/soft-delete-pattern-for-entity.html)):

```
[Table("EntityA")]
public partial class EntityA
{
    public int EntityAId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }


    public virtual EntityB PrimaryEntityB { get; set; }

    public virtual EntityB AlternativeEntityB { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}

[Table("EntityB")]
public partial class EntityB
{
    public int EntityBId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("PrimaryEntityB")]
    public virtual ICollection<EntityA> EntityAsViaPrimary { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty( "AlternativeEntityB" )]
    public virtual ICollection<EntityA> EntityAsViaAlternative { get; set; }
}

public partial class TestEntities : DbContext
{
    public TestEntities()
        : base("TestEntities")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer( new DatabaseInitializer() );
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<EntityA>()
            .Map( emc =>
                {
                    emc.Requires( "IsDeleted" ).HasValue( false );
                } )
                .Ignore( a => a.IsDeleted );
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        foreach( var entry in this.ChangeTracker.Entries<EntityA>() )
        {
            if( entry.State == EntityState.Deleted )
            {
                SoftDelete( entry );
            }
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    private void SoftDelete( DbEntityEntry entry )
    {
        var entityType = entry.Entity.GetType();

        var tableName = GetTableName( entityType );
        var pkName = GetPrimaryKeyName( entityType );

        var deleteSql = string.Format( "update {0} set IsDeleted = 1 where {1} = @id",
            tableName,
            pkName );

        Database.ExecuteSqlCommand( deleteSql, new SqlParameter( "@id", entry.OriginalValues[ pkName ] ) );

        entry.State = EntityState.Detached;
    }

    private string GetPrimaryKeyName( Type type )
    {
        return GetEntitySet( type ).ElementType.KeyMembers[ 0 ].Name;
    }

    private string GetTableName( Type type )
    {
        EntitySetBase es = GetEntitySet( type );

        return string.Format( "[{0}].[{1}]",
            es.MetadataProperties[ "Schema" ].Value,
            es.MetadataProperties[ "Table" ].Value );
    }
    private EntitySetBase GetEntitySet( Type type )
    {
        ObjectContext octx = ( ( IObjectContextAdapter )this ).ObjectContext;

        string typeName = ObjectContext.GetObjectType( type ).Name;

        var es = octx.MetadataWorkspace
                        .GetItemCollection( DataSpace.SSpace )
                        .GetItems<EntityContainer>()
                        .SelectMany( c => c.BaseEntitySets
                                        .Where( e => e.Name == typeName ) )
                        .FirstOrDefault();

        if( es == null )
            throw new ArgumentException( "Entity type not found in GetTableName", typeName );

        return es;
    }

    public DbSet<EntityA> EntityAs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EntityB> EntityBs { get; set; }
}
```

Application code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using( var db = new TestEntities() )
        {
            var a0 = new EntityA()
                {
                    EntityAId = 1,
                    Description = "hi"
                };

            var a1 = new EntityA()
                {
                    EntityAId = 2,
                    Description = "bye"
                };

            db.EntityAs.Add( a0 );
            db.EntityAs.Add( a1 );

            var b = new EntityB()
            {
                EntityBId = 1,
                Description = "Big B"
            };

            a1.PrimaryEntityB = b;

            db.SaveChanges();

            // this prints "1"
            Console.WriteLine( b.EntityAsViaPrimary.Count() );

            db.EntityAs.Remove( a1 );

            db.SaveChanges();

            // this prints "0"
            Console.WriteLine( b.EntityAsViaPrimary.Count() );
        }

        var input = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks promising! We already use the Map() method for mapping inherited properties. Can I chain a second Map() statement to this, or do I need to combine it with the previous one? For clarity: `modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().Map(m => m.MapInheritedProperties());` would become `modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().Map(m => m.MapInheritedProperties()).Map(m => m.Requires("IsDeleted").HasValue(false));` ?

Comment: use curly braces to enable multiple lines in your map expression.  I'll updated the solution

Comment: actually, I don't think the `.Ignore` call should be there, so I removed it

Comment: It's good because I learned about Ignore today :) But in this scenario we don't use it because we actually use most audit fields. It is redundant though, since it's always false.

Comment: Sorry I pulled the answer away from you, but I'm facing an issue with this implementation. Please see my updated question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what's new about your question? what's the problem

Comment: You probably just missed it, I just edited it. Sorry, shouldve edited before I told you ;)

Comment: Ok, try adding the `.Ignore( p => p.IsDeleted )` call back

Comment: I'm now getting another Exception : `The context cannot be used while the model is being created. ...` But isn't using .Ignore the same as using the NotMapped property? If it is, how can I still address the IsDeleted property, set it to true, and save that change in the database?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45998/discussion-between-moho-and-flater)

Comment: Have to go to meeting now. I'll be back in roughly an hour.

Comment: I tested myself and this solution works with the `.Ignore` call.  Alternatively, you can remove the `IsDeleted` property from the base class.  The new error you're experiencing is another issue.

Answer (score 0):

Four years later, I finally stumbled on a library that does exactly what I want.

[EntityFramework.DynamicFilter](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters).

```
modelBuilder.Filter("IsDeleted", (ISoftDelete d) => d.IsDeleted, false);
```

The above snippet ensures that the soft-deleted items are not retrieved. This affects **both** direct queries (`db.Set<Foo>().ToList()`) and indirect loadaed entities `db.Set<Foo>().Include(e => e.Bars).ToList()`), thus completely hiding the soft deleted entities from view.

---

For completeness' sake, I've combined this with an override to `SaveChanges()` which converts hard deletes to soft deletes before committing to the database.

This means that developers are able to safely use hard delete logic, and they'll never even realize that the context is using soft deletes. They don't need to know, they don't need to care, they can't forget to implement it the right way, they never need to write a check for the `IsDeleted` flag.

Answer (score -1):

You can do soft delete like this:

1. In OnModelCreating add an IsDeleted discriminator to every entity that can be soft deleted
2. Override SaveChanges and find all the entries to be deleted
3. Run SQL on these entries to set the IsDeleted discriminator then set their state to "detached"
4. Change any unique indexes to ignore any soft deleted records

You can find working code at this answer:
[How to soft delete using Entity Framework Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18985828/150342)

And that code was picked up by this Blog:
http://netpl.blogspot.com/2013/10/soft-delete-pattern-for-entity.html