# Entity Framework: Soft Delete and Table per Type

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm trying to implement the Soft Delete pattern using the following approach:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18985828/213725

However I have difficulties implement it for Table Per Type inheritance. Let's say I have `Entity` mapped to table "Entity" and its descendant `ConcreteEntity` mapped to table "ConcreteEntity". I have the `IsDeleted` column in the table "Entity" to designate whether the entity is "deleted" or not.
What I trying to do in `OnModelCreating` is something like the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>()
    .Map<Entity>(m =>
    {
        m.ToTable("Entity");
        m.Requires("IsDeleted").HasValue(false);
    })
    .Map<ConcreteEntity>(m =>
    {
        m.ToTable("ConcreteEntity");
    });
```

I doesn't work though. I'm getting the following error:

> (59,10) : error 3032: Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines
>   59, 142:EntityTypes Entity, ConcreteEntity are being mapped to the
>   same rows in table Entity. Mapping conditions can be used to
>   distinguish the rows that these types are mapped to.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the combining TPT and the Soft Delete pattern using the discriminator is quite tricky.

So, in order to make it work, I made `Entity` abstract and moved `IsDeleted` column to to the `ConcreteEntity` table. Then I changed mappings as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>().Map(m => m.ToTable("Entity"));

modelBuilder.Entity<ConcreteEntity>().Map(m => 
{
    m.ToTable("ConcreteEntity");
    m.Requires("IsDeleted").HasValue(false);
});
```

I'm not convinced that it is the best way it can be done, but at least it works.

Comment: I have the same requirement with EF7. Are you still satisfied with your solution? :-)

Answer (score 1):

The soft delete technique uses a discriminator field to ensure that EF always filters out soft deleted entities. But discriminator fields were designed for the purpose of implementing inheritance with Table-Per-Hierarchy. I believe that EF is falling over before it even gets to the `ToTable("ConcreteEntity")`

That is because EF interprets this line: `m.Requires("IsDeleted").HasValue(false);` to mean that you are using TPH and an Entity will be retrieved from a single table by adding `IsDeleted=false` to the sql. I do not believe that EF will let you combine discriminators and Table-Per-Type inheritance.