# How to automatically filter out logically deleted entities from EF queries?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Looking to see if there is a way to filter out logical/soft deleted entities by default, but also is overridable so that I can fetch all entities as needed?

Comment: Could you clarify want you mean by "default"? Which layer are you wanting/expecting to handle this?

Comment: You could use inheritance. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18985828/150342

Comment: By "default" I mean that the normal behavior for a entity that is "deleted by the user" would be to simply mark that entity's "IsDeleted" field as true.  But I want to be able to override this behavior so that I can "really" delete entities from the database if so desired.