# Exclude entities based on property IsDeleted value when loading from DbSet<TEntity>

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using entity framework and in my context I've done some stuff like:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
    {
        if (entry.Entity is Base entity)
        {
            if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                entity.Created = DateTime.UtcNow;
                entity.Modified = DateTime.UtcNow;
            }
            else if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
            {
                entity.Modified = DateTime.UtcNow;
            }
        }
    }
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Where Base is:

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Modified { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
```

Now what I'm trying to do is when I load properties using my context like:

```
_context.MyEntities.AsEnumerable(something);
```

I want it to select all entities that have the `IsDeleted` property set to false. Is it possible to do this in the `DbContext` like I'm making changes by overriding `SaveChanges()`

I can see that there is a method to override, but not sure how to go about it:

```
public override DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>()
{
    return base.Set<TEntity>();
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `_context.MyEntities.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted).ToList()`? Calling `.AsEnumerable()` will download the entire table into memory, beware.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto No, I don't want to do it like that because it would require me to check for the deleted flag each time I want to load entities. I was wondering if there's a way to exclude the deleted entities on a more lower level using the context object.

Comment: What version of EF? You can handle soft deletes transparently in 6+ and Core 2+

Comment: @AluanHaddad Indeed using EF6 and MVC5.

Comment: @px06 if you want soft deletes, watch [this presentation by Rowan Miller](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2014/DEV-B417). See ~11 minutes in for soft deletes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you need to add something like this in `DbContext`

```
public DbSet<MyEntity> ExistingMyEntities {
    get { return MyEntities.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted); }
}
```

So then as you want you can use context object to retrieve not deleted entities.

**UPDATE**

Also you can filter by IsDeleted with model builder (if there is used soft delete [How can I automatically filter out soft deleted entities with Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698793/how-can-i-automatically-filter-out-soft-deleted-entities-with-entity-framework))

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual IDbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntities>()
            .Map(m => m.Requires("IsDeleted")).HasValue(false).Ignore(m => m.IsDeleted);
    }
}
```

I was misinformed with Ignore, but as Jan Muncinsky noticed there can be used `HasValue` method for filtering.

Comment: `Ignore(m => m.IsDeleted)` does not filter anything, it will just ignore property during mapping.

Comment: @JanMuncinsky probably you are right, I've read somewhere it filters... I'm trying to find it.

Comment: https://putshello.wordpress.com/2014/08/20/entity-framework-soft-deletes-are-easy/

Comment: you could filter them by: `modelBuilder.Entity<Base>().Map(m => m.Requires("IsDeleted").HasValue(false))`. But it would require to drop `IsDeleted` out of the model and leave it in only in DB, so it's not useful in this case.

Comment: @JanMuncinsky it's not necessary should be out of the model. But there is no a reason to have it in model, value of the property will be false for all retrieved entities.

Comment: Not sure about this. I would guess that deleting is performed just by setting `IsDeleted` to true and than calling 'SaveChanges' on context, but in this case `IsDeleted` is stripped out of mapping, so it wouldn't save anything.

Comment: @JanMuncinsky I suppose there is used soft delete another way than through the property https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698793/how-can-i-automatically-filter-out-soft-deleted-entities-with-entity-framework